# No GUI shell in Ubuntu 16.04 after update - NVIDIA graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Over night, so possibly after an update, my GUI login into Ubuntu 16.04 does not work anymore.

So I open another console (Ctrl+Alt+F3) and everything works fine.

I tried the stuff I found elsewhere: something with removing ~/.Xauthority.

In ~/.xsession-errors file I found at least the keyword, that others used to detect their errors: something with GLX.

In the end I did:

```
sudo apt autoremove nvidia-*
sudo apt install nvidia-current
```

GUI login still does not work.

.xsession-errors says:

extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: .....
...

Comment: `nividia-current` actually installs an old driver meant only for legacy hardware. Probably NOT the one you need.

Comment: And how do I find out which one I need?

Comment: Geforce.com or nvidia.com to search for the supported driver versions. Do not install from there. Install the recommended version from the official Ubuntu repositories, if available, or add a PPA providing newer versions (only required for brand new chipsets). But before all that you need to uninstall all (and the command you used doesn't do that), use `sudo apt purge nvidia*`.

Answer (score 2):

for all the dummies like me:
first

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

find out which graphics card you have with:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

then look up which driver you need on nvidia.com
search for it in the repositories with

```
 sudo apt-cache search nvidia-*
```

(or add further numbers to shorten the list). Install it with

```
sudo apt install nvidia-YOURNUMBER
```

then

```
reboot
```